# Envio de dos formularios para agregar a base de datos

Tags: php

Tengo la siguiene situación y les solicito su ayuda para poderlos resolver, de antemano gracias por su ayuda

Tengo dos formularios form1 y form2, en el primero tom0 unos datos y realizo unos cálculos

```
<form id="form1"  method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
...
     <input type="submit" name="guardarcal" value="Guardar Datos" />
</form>
```

En el formulario dos tomo unos valores propios de producto junto con los calculos que se hicieron en el primer formulario.

```
<form id="form2"  method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
...
     <input type="submit" name="guardarinfo" value="Guardar Datos" />
</form>
```

Ahora bien, si yo les doy guardar por separado el codigo funciona como se espera y guarda la información a la tabla corerespondiente en la base de datos

```
if(!isset($_POST["guardarcal"])) {  
Guardar_Cal($num_order);
}
```

Ok, aqui viene el problema, como pueden ver el codigo funciona cada cual por separado, pero lo mas práctico debe de ser que con un solo botón de salvar  guarde los dos formualarios y esto es justamente lo que no he podido hacer, intenté con algo asi pero no ejecuta el codigo php para guardar en las tablas

```
<script>
function envarfrn(){        
    document.getElementById("form1").submit().;
 }
```

Hay alguna forma de agregar el name del input del botón para que se pueda ejecutar el if del php ?, osea para que esto funcione

```
if(!isset($_POST["guardarcal"])) {
```

Guardar_Cal($num_order);
}

En otras palabras lo que necesito es guardar los dos formularios de una sola vez o con un mismo botón

De ante mano gracias por su ayuda

**ACTUALIZACION**

En el formulario tengo  name="guardarcal"  como se ve acontinuacion.

```
<form id="form1"  method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
...
     <input type="submit" name="guardarcal" value="Guardar Datos" />
</form>
```

Ahora bien, el codigo que hace el guardado de los datos en la base de datos lo tneog de la siguiente forma. Este se activa cuando yo le doy clic al boton **Guadar Datos** del formulario enteriomente puesto,

```
if(!isset($_POST["guardarcal"])) {  
Guardar_Cal($num_order);
}
```

Lo que pasa es que al ejecutar los dos formularios con el codigo sugerido no se hace que se dispare el varlos de **guardarcal** y por ende no se ejecuta el codigo para salvar los datos, que se puede hacer ahi? GRacias por la ayuda

Comment: Has probado guardar los datos con AJAX haciendo una serializacion de cada formulario y ejecutando un AJAX para cada formulario?

Answer (score 3):

Para hacer eso lo único que tendrías que hacer es añadir un botón fuera de las dos etiquetas `form` y programar un evento, por ejemplo en `JavaScript` que detecte si se ha hecho click en dicho botón y enviar la información.

Quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
     [...]
</form>

<form id="form2" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
     [...]
</form>

<button onclick="enviaDatos()">Enviar</button>

<script>
function enviaDatos() {
   document.form1.submit();
   document.form2.submit();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hola @itsnesky, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, vieras que eso que me comentas es parecido a lo que estaba probando, probe lo que me pusiste pero sigue sin enviar la información, osea no me guarda la información en la base de datos, este es el bton que tengo en el formulario
`<input type="submit" name="guardarmad" value="Guardar Datos" />` y este es el que envia a la base de datos `if(!isset($_POST["guardarcal"])) {... }` Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Dentro de `if(!isset($_POST["guardarcal"]))` puedes llamar a la función `enviaDatos` para que haga el submit.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que ese if nunca se llega a ejecutar, no se porque, si lo hago con el propioboton de guardar si se ejecuta y llega a esa if, pero si lo hago de la forma que mejos conversado no se llega a ejecutar por ende no guarda en la BS

Comment: He estado tratnaod con el codigo, pero solo se carga el POST, de hecho he tratado de que en el action los dos vayan al mismo archivo.php pero no he tenido suerte

Comment: Sé un poco más específico y actualiza tu pregunta para que veamos el estado en el que está... si no es complicado ayudarte.

Comment: Hola @itsnesky , acabo de actualiza lo que te comentaba sobre el llamado al codigo, espero que esto ayude a que me comprendas como estan las cosas, de antemano, muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Hola @itsnesky , algun comentario compañero ? gracias por la ayuda